# Program compiles fine but crashes with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, bluej

I have written five classes, which, in a nutshell, serve the purpose of creating a GUI and recording participants for a conference.  I have built panels and added them, FocusListeners, ActionListeners, ItemListeners.

From what I can gather, the message I am getting upon crash is related to my Classpath, but I don't really know how to fix it.  Here is the code where the crash takes place (it is when I add the ActionListeners for the two buttons for my panel:

```
private void buildButtonPanel()
{
   //create the buttonpanel
   buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
   //create the buttons
   calculate = new JButton("Calculate Charges");
   clear = new JButton    ("Clear");
   //add listeners to the buttons
   ConferenceHandler handler = new ConferenceHandler(this);
   calculate.addActionListener(handler);             //crash occurs on this line
   clear.addActionListener(handler);
   //create a text area
   JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5,30); 
   textArea.setLineWrap(true); textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
   //add a scrollbar to the textarea
   JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textArea);
   //add everything to the buttonpanel
   buttonPanel.add(calculate); buttonPanel.add(clear); buttonPanel.add(scroll);
}
```

The crash message I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ConferenceHandler
    at ConferenceGUI.buildButtonPanel(ConferenceGUI.java:63)
    at ConferenceGUI.<init>(ConferenceGUI.java:33)
    at IsItWorking.<init>(IsItWorking.java:16)
    at IsItWorking.main(IsItWorking.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ConferenceHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at ConferenceGUI.buildButtonPanel(ConferenceGUI.java:63)
    at ConferenceGUI.<init>(ConferenceGUI.java:33)
    at IsItWorking.<init>(IsItWorking.java:16)
    at IsItWorking.main(IsItWorking.java:28)
    at __SHELL0.run(__SHELL0.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:774)
```

I know there are a lot of people here with a lot of experience, and I cannot find any help on the interwebs on this one.

Comment: Did you tell java where to find `ConferenceHandler` by using `-classpath` arguments? Like `java -classpath /path/to/directory/with/compiled/ConferenceHandler program`

Comment: fair enough about the homework tag, but I've posted a couple of questions without it, and people always add it.  As for telling java where to find ConferenceHandler (and I apologize for sounding stupid - homework questions are asked by newbs) I am using Blue Jay, and all I have to do is click on the main, and the program runs.  I have no idea how to do this from command line.

Comment: I'm not sure about the BlueJ part (never used it), but how about when you put all your classes in a package? That's also how it normally works. Technically, packageless classes are invisible to classes inside a package.

Comment: Gotcha.  I have a package of five classes. So yes, they are all in a package.

Comment: The stacktrace indicates otherwise. They're packageless (in other words, in the *default* package, if BlueJ is telling that you literally somehow).

Comment: I wish I knew what that meant.....

Comment: Your source files should all have `package some.thing.like.this;` at the top. If not, they are in the default package and most IDEs will tell you this is discouraged. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As for telling java where to find ConferenceHandler (and I apologize for sounding stupid - homework questions are asked by newbs) I am using Blue Jay, and all I have to do is click on the main, and the program runs. I have no idea how to do this from command line.

The place to look is in the documentation for the `java` command; e.g. [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).  Pay particular attention to the stuff that talks about the classpath and the different ways of setting it.  Also read [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

---

> I realized that it was a problem with classpath, and no matter what I did, I couldn't fix it. So I took all of the original classes, and pasted them all into a new folder, and it worked like a charm.

That's a Voodoo solution.  You really need to understand the problem.

To that end, lets revisit some comments above:

> The stacktrace indicates otherwise. They're packageless (in other words, in the default package, if BlueJ is telling that you literally somehow). – @BalusC
>
> I wish I knew what that meant..... - @unit

What @BalusC means is that the stack trace tells you the full name of the class that it was trying to load.

```
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ConferenceHandler
    ...
```

And the full name (in this case) is `ConsoleHandler` ... not `some.pkg.ConsoleHandler`.

What is not entirely clear is why this is occurring, but I *suspect* that you were actually running old `.class` files that didn't match the source code you were looking at.  And your Voodoo solution could well have "fixed" this by replacing the old `.class` files with new stuff.  But if that's the case, you need to understand what is wrong with the way you are building / deploying.  Otherwise, you'll trip over this kind of thing over and over again.

Comment: I realized that it was a problem with classpath, and no matter what I did, I couldn't fix it.  So I took all of the original classes, and pasted them all into a new folder, and it worked like a charm.